# Accidentally deleted my kubernetes config

Tags: kubernetes

I accidentally deleted my kubeconfig file having server on Google Cloud, how can I generate it back without destroying my cluster?

Comment: if you know where you can contact the api server, and know how to authenticate yourself, the you should be fine with `kubectl config` command to generate a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a cluster in [Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/), you can run `gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTERNAME` to create a new kubeconfig file locally.

If you used the GCE setup scripts to create your cluster, then your best bet is to copy a kubeconfig file off of a worker node onto your local machine.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct without testing it yet. All worker nodes does not contain any config file. Also, I created the cluster using the https://get.k8s.io/ script.

Comment: So it sounds like you are running on GCE. The worker nodes to contain a kubeconfig file, it's just in a different location that on a client machine. Take a look at `/srv/salt-overlay/salt/kubelet/kubeconfig` or `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig` (it should be in both places). Note that you need to be root to read either file.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I was searching for config file didn't thought it would be kubeconfig